# When specing a namespaced class how do I stub the parent class?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

```
# models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
end

# models/event/timeline.rb
class Event::Timeline
  # ...
end

# spec/event/timeline_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'models/event/timeline' # <- fails since "event" is not required

describe Event::Timeline do
  it '' do
    # ...
  end
end
```

I do not want to `require 'event'` since it would mean also requiring all of its dependencies which are not nessesary for the spec.

Comment: I don not think you should do this. Just load the parent class.

Your code should be tested in an environment that will also be used in production, everything else is useless ;)

Comment: I'm isolating Event::Timeline from everything else, this is more of a unit test than an integration test.

Comment: But all child classes must interact with the parent classes. Else there is no reason for a subclass.

Comment: there is one option, but i would __NOT__ recommend it, anyway: put this before requiring your timeline source: `class Event ; end`. but as i said, i wouldn't do this, better rearrange your namespaces / class names

Comment: I have to revoke all my statements! Because I did not realized Event::Timeline is NOT a subclass. Sorry.

Comment: @mbj No problem :) As you say its not a subclass, its namespaced, so in Event I have `def timeline; Timeline.new(self); end`. :)

Comment: @Kris I still think it is valuable to "fully" load the parent namespace. The constant lookup is affected by the constants in the parent namespace, so a spec should always run in the environment as in production.

Answer (score 1):

You use `stub_const` method from RSpec:

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-13/docs/mutating-constants

but probably simpler just to use `class Event; end` as Marian suggested.

In response to your comment, does it need to be declared above the `describe` block? If not perhaps try

```
describe Event::Timeline do
  let(:fake_class) { Class.new }

  before do
    stub_const("Event", fake_class)
  end

  it '' do
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't use `stub_const` outside an `it` block. I tried adding `class Event; end` but it breaks other specs when `Event` gets required because it has already been defined with a different sub class (`Object`, not `ActiveRecord::Base`).